# bash: duplication of file descriptors

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

`man bash` says this on redirection:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the
> command
>
> ```
>           ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs  both  standard output and standard error to the file dirlist,
> while the command
>
> ```
>           ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
> error was  duplicated  from  the  standard  output  before  the
> standard output was redirected to dirlist.

I really do not understand the part:

> the standard error was duplicated from the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

From my perspective `>` just means redirection, like `ls > dirlist` redirects output of `ls` into file `dirlist`.

So `2>&1` should redirect stderr to stdout, which then should get redirected to `dirlist` (`> dirlist`). However, apparently only stdout gets redirected to `dirlist` then.

What's the business with this "stream A duplicated from stream B"?

Comment: This isn't shell-specific at all, by the way. You'd get the same behaviors performing this same set of operations in the same order (copying a file descriptor pointing to `dirlist` to FD 1, then copying FD 1 to FD 2) in C using the `fdup2()` call with no shell at all.

Comment: ...this is also the topic of [BashFAQ #55](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Comment: (aside: this question really calls to mind for me the classic essay [The Law of Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/); shell redirections are a layer on top of an older, lower-level abstraction, and once you know how they're built it all makes sense; but if you're learning it from scratch and don't know what it's built on, it's easy to get a wrong impression).

Answer (score 5):

Shell redirections literally just invoke the syscall `dup2()`. Quoting from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html --

> `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);`
>
> The dup() system call allocates a new file descriptor that refers to the same open file description as the descriptor oldfd.

This isn't actually doing anything like "redirecting streams" -- instead, it's changing the table of open files to make a file handle at one position in the table be pointed to from another location in the table.

So, let's look at your first example, `ls > dirlist 2>&1`

- The file `dirlist` is opened with `open(2)`.
- `dup2()` is used to copy the file handle created by `open()` to FD 1 (the default for `>`), and the dynamically-created handle is closed.
- `dup2()` is used to copy FD 1 to FD 2.

...net result: both FD 1 and FD 2 point to `dirlist`.

---

Now, let's look at your next example, `ls 2>&1 >dirlist`

- `dup2()` is used to copy **whatever was previously opened at FD 1 to FD 2**
- `open()` is used to open the file `dirlist`
- `dup2()` is used to copy the handle on dirlist to FD 1, and the dynamically-created handle is closed.

...net result: FD 2 now points to the prior value of FD 1, and FD 1 now points to `dirlist`.

Answer (score 1):

Your manual is a bit different from the one available at the GNU website, but take a look at [Duplicating File Descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors):

> The redirection operator [n]<&word is used to duplicate input file descriptors. If word expands to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of that file descriptor...The operator [n]>&word is used similarly to duplicate output file descriptors.

So when you write `2>&1` you're saying you want file descriptor 2 to become a **copy** of file descriptor 1. It doesn't literally get connected to file descriptor 1, it just points at the same place. Since it's just a copy, changes to file descriptor 1 don't automatically apply back to file descriptor 2. That's why the order matters.